# Comparing Database values with an input value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm attempting to create a register page for users to use.
However, this allows users to have the same Username, in which I don't want to happen. I've wrote a piece of code, which I assumed would work but failed miserably.

```
Managers manager = new Managers();

//Compares to database to find any duplicate usernames
if (manager.Username == txtUsername.Text)
{
    lblUsername.Text = "Please enter a different username!";
    lblUsername.Visible = true;
}
```

Only gave the relevant part.

I was wondering if someone could explain to me what I have done wrong about this? `Managers` is my database.

Edit-
I added in a foreach loop, however was still accepted values.

```
List<Managers> manage = new List<Managers>();
Managers manager = new Managers();
foreach (Managers m in manage)
{
    if (manager.Username == txtUsername.Text)
    {
        lblUsername.Text = "Please enter a different username!";
        lblUsername.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxpGI.png Showing the Error when program is ran

Comment: What does it *not* do?

Comment: Although, it looks as though you're missing a loop, as you're only going to be checking the first "Managers" record with that code. Possibly something like: foreach(Managers m in manager) { // do your check here }

Comment: It simply does not search the managers database for any login with the same username. I will attempt a loop just now.

Comment: You say "Managers is my database". Are you sure? On the face of it, it looks like a simple class that represents a manager.

Comment: My database is called 'ManagersDbContext'. I just realised my flaw. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're still checking "manager.Username" rather than m.Username - to now satisfy your loop structure.

Comment: Thanks LokiSinclair and Ben. I realised that "manager.Username" was one of my flaws.

Comment: So you're all fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like :

```
var query = (from c in db.Users where c.UserName== userName select c);
if (query.Count() > 0)
{
    // Message : user is exist 
}
else
{
   // register user
}
```

Edit :

Use lambda expressions

```
if (Manager.Users.Select(d => d).Where(d => d.UserName == UserName).ToList().Count() > 0)
{
        // the Item is Exist in the list
}
else
{
        Manager.Users.Add(new Users { UserName = Username, Pass= Password});
}
```